# Replace character in a string, using an array in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a STRING and I want to replace some character, and this characters are in an array. Here is my code :

```js
let arrayParam = [];
arrayParam.push('X');
arrayParam.push('Y');
arrayParam.push('Z');

let stringToFilter = 'Y0000000';

let stringFiltered;

for (let i = 0; i < arrayParam.length; i++) {
  stringFiltered = stringToFilter.replace(arrayParam[i], '');
  console.log(`array:${arrayParam[i]}     stringFiltered:${stringFiltered}`);
};
```

This result in the console :

```
element:A     stringFiltered : Y0000000
element:B     stringFiltered : 0000000
element:C     stringFiltered : Y0000000
```

I don't understand, my var is declared outside the loop why it doesn't remember the change ?

Comment: you are not updating the value of the variable *stringToFilter*, it is always 'Y0000000', update it to the same value of *stringFiltered*

Comment: The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. so `"Y00..".replace("X"," ")` return Y00...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to update the stringToFilter.

```js
for(let i=0 ; i < arrayParam.length; i++ ) {
  stringFiltered = stringToFilter.replace(arrayParam[i], '');
  console.log(`array:${arrayParam[i]}  stringFiltered:${stringFiltered}`);
  stringToFilter = stringFiltered;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The result is what you'd expect, in the last iteration `stringFiltered` is being updated to:

```
"Y0000000".replace("Z", '');
```

which results in `"Y0000000"`.

A nicer way to achieve what you're trying would be:

```
const regex = new RegExp(arrayParam.join('|'), 'g');
stringFiltered = stringToFilter.replace(regex, '');
```